# Android GPS position give just first number

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, location

Here is my app:

```
public class HlavnaAktivita extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
...
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.w("myApp", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    }
```

When I give to emulator for example 48.590007 and 17.824579, it just write "17.0". I tried http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/?s=GPS this tutorial (from StackOverflow) and when I run that app, it write good postition, but on map is just rounded position (17, 48) (position according to maps.google.com is good, but on map is cca 100km wrong).

What could be the problem? I tried a lot of tutorials but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just my mistake - I forget to add (). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact position on the map you need 2 parameters:
Latitude and Longitude of a Point.
`GeoPoint` accepts latitude and longitude in microdegrees so try to create your point like this to get better accuracy:

```
double lati = location.getLatitude();
double longi = location.getLongitude();
GeoPoint geo_point= new GeoPoint((int)(lati * 1e6),(int)(longi * 1e6));
```

Comment: yes I know that... this is simplified code, but when I had this, double lati also didn't have accurate position (this exact code - (int)(lati * 1e6) gave just int 17000000 and int 48000000... so it's just the same thing)   as I said, .akp from that page showed good numbers of my position, but on the map it was on the position 17000000 and 4800000... on google maps is's here http://goo.gl/0ivrN and I am 75km from that position...

Answer (score 0):

It converts somewhere your number to int. To avoid it try someting like:

```
Log.w("myApp", String.valueOf((float) location.getLatitude()));
```

Comment: thank you, but this worked for me at the end:geo_auto = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000), (int) (lng * 1000000)); () was missing and did the problem